# I can't figure out why my adapter is not updating my recyclerview

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-recyclerview, onresume

I have read some similar questions and and i have tried to get it work but  i can't understand why my adapter is not updating my recyclerview after return from my SaveItem activity. So i have two tabs: ALL notes and Favourite notes. To be more specific: [App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSpY7.png)
.

**When i press the floating action button from the bottom it starts a new activity where i can record a new note, but when i return to MainActivity the first fragment it's not updating my recyclerview:**

Here is where I fill my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new NoteAdapter(fillAdapter(),this,getActivity());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
}
```

Here is where I try to update my recyclerview:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.addAll(fillAdapter());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my `addAll` method:

```
public class NoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolderNote> {
    // Other codes....
    public void addAll(List<Note> newNotes) {
        this.notes.clear();
        this.notes.addAll(newNotes);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your fillAdapter() function? And how do you add another item to the List<Note> in the second activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a list of `Note` in your `Fragment` class.

```
private List<Note> allNotes;
```

Then inside your `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    allNotes = fillAdapter();

    adapter = new NoteAdapter(allNotes, this, getActivity());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
}
```

Now to update your list call the `fillAdapter` function again to popuate the `allNotes` list again and modify your `onResume` like this.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    allNotes = fillAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

The `addAll` function has no necessity right now. Remove the function from your `NoteAdapter`.

The key thing is the reference of your list which is being passed to the adapter.